# Using FTP Proxy with apache commons-net

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I want to set up an FTP connection using a proxy server with Apache's commons-net.

But looking at this [Does FTPClient support FTP connections through an FTP proxy server?](http://wiki.apache.org/jakarta-commons/Net/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) has me worried.

I have to meddle with the system properties and the Sun docs state that "If *socksProxyHost* is specified then all TCP sockets will use the SOCKS proxy server to establish a connection or accept one."
WTH? All TCP sockets? What about my database connections? Or other FTP connections i might want to open at the same time not using a proxy? Will they all be affected?

Is there some other way to do it that doesn't mess with the rest of my application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have several ways of using proxies in Java, especially from version 1.5.

1. Using System Properties: quick & powerfull but limited flexibility

   - You can use use a SOCKS proxy for all TCP connections.
   - You can also set a proxy per protocol, doable for HTTP, FTP and HTTPS
   - For both methods, you can specify a list of hosts that **will not use proxy**
2. Using the [`java.net.Proxy`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/Proxy.html) class (Java 1.5+) to set (or not) a `Proxy` per `Connection`
3. Impleting a [`java.net.ProxySelector`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/ProxySelector.html) (idem) which will determine a `Proxy` for each `Connection` according to your criteria

See the [detailled Sun technote on networking & proxies](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html).

Comment: Well, nowadays the `SocketFactory` is the way to go -- quoting Commons-Net 3.3 documentation https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/SocketClient.html  *"Of special note is the setSocketFactory method ... This is especially useful for adding SSL or proxy support "*

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter You can add this as another answer, which it is :). Over time, it should get more upvotes than this one and be more visible to people coming back to this question.

Comment: you can also update your "authoritative answer"... I'm feeling lazy 0:)